# Remove stop words from list using only Numpy in Python

Tags: python, list

I am working on removing stop words in python using only numpy. The stopwords file is imported as a list. So here is what I came up:

method 1, I try to loop through the stop words list, and remove everyone from the tw_line

```
# loop through the stop words list, and remove each one from the splitted    line list
 for line in stopwords:
     if line in words:
         words.remove(line) 
         continue
     print (tw_line)
```

Result: NO stop words are removed.

```
0 my whole body feels itchy and like its on fire
```

method 2, I try to loop the word through the stopwords list,

```
# loop through the line, and check with stop words, if not in stop words, add to clean_line
clean_line=[]
tw_line.split(" ")
  for line in tw_line:
      if line in stopwords:
          clean_line.append(line)            
  print(clean_line)
```

Result: All words are broken into characters

```
['m', 'y', 'w', 'h', 'o', 'l', 'e', 'b', 'o', 'd', 'y', 'f', 'e', 'e', 'l', 's', 'i', 'c', 'h', 'y', 'a', 'n', 'd', 'l', 'i', 'k', 'e', 'i', 's', 'o', 'n', 'f', 'i', 'r', 'e']
```

Any help?

Comment: What is the question?  And how does `numpy` relate to this?  It would be helpful if you would include an example of what the data looks like.  See how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example

Comment: the `.split` member function you use in method 2 is not  working "in place" (How could it, it is producing a new type (list from string)) you have to _assign_ its return value either to `tw_line` or a new variable.

Comment: numpy is the only lib allowed to use...so i can't use built-in method in other libs.

Answer (score 0):

Try apply this:

```
>>> str1 = "my whole body feels itchy and like its on fire"
>>> str1.split()
 ['my', 'whole', 'body', 'feels', 'itchy', 'and', 'like', 'its', 'on', 'fire']
>>>
```

And then remove words which are in stopwords. BTW, I don't see any numpy here.

Answer (score 0):

You should print word not tw_line since word is where you removed the stopword?

```
for line in stopwords:
 if line in words:
     words.remove(line) 
     continue
 print (words)
```

Answer (score 0):

The method 2 is clearly what you want to do. However, there are some things you can improve:

- as Paul Panzer stated, `split` doesn't work in place so you need to do
  `tw_list = tw_line.split(" ")`
- You could make use of list comprehension rather than looping (or even a generator if you intend to `join` afterward).
  `clean_line = [word for word in tw_list if word not in stopwords]`
- I saw from your code comment that `stopwords` is a list. You might want to make it a set for efficiency reasons ( https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Comment: I tried it, it worked by itself. When I put it in function, the line gave a weird result:  `print(stopwords[:10]) ['a', 'able', 'about', 'above', 'abst', 'accordance', 'according', 'accordingly', 'across', 'act']`

Comment: `def remove_stopwords (tw): with open('stop_words.txt') as f: 
        stopwords=f.readlines()
    for index,line in enumerate(stopwords):
        line = line.strip('\n')
        stopwords[index]=line
    remove_punc(stopwords) 
    
    for index, line in enumerate(tw):   
        clean_line=[] 
        clean_line = [word for word in line if word not in stopwords] 
        line=string.join(clean_line) 
        tw[index]=line  #store line back to tw
    return tw[:5] `

Comment: `['0   t t   t t t t 2 1     A     t t         Y     t   D   C     T   D   t     t   D \n',
 '0     t   t t     t   t     F     t t   t     t         t     S   t     B \n',
 '0   K   I       t     t     M   t     5 0     T   t     t     \n',
 '0           t       t       \n',
 '0   t       t   t     t                   I   t           t   \n']`

Comment: Looks like it was removing in as of a string, not a list anymore. But i clearly defined them as list.

Comment: Ok, I think I see what's going on here. You are trying to think line by line, whereas the easiest might be to think in terms of strings.
You should have a function `remove_stopwords` which takes as arguments a string and a list of stopwords and returns a string without the stopwords (so just return ` " ".join(clean_line)` in what I suggested).
Then you can apply that function line by line if your file is too big but frankly, in most cases, it can be done straightforwardly.

Comment: I need to write a function `remove_stopwords`, that is the assignment. And I hope to know what's wrong with my code.

Comment: I understand, then just rename the function I was talking about to `remove_stopwords_string` then apply it to a file line by line.